# Grab automatically content from a website to my Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to to grab automatically content from a website to my google sheet.

I am having the following problem.
[image]

What is wrong in my formlua?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ommit the S from table.
It is table not tables.

https://youtube.com/video/d3YptmCbM9Q/edit

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is:

```
=IMPORTHTML("url"; "table"; 1)
```